How to configure Delegating handler in Flurl clientless configuration
Flurl website document shows it has a configuration which allows to pass in Delegating Handlers.
https://flurl.dev/docs/configuration/
It would be at the end of the above link.
All code is configured in the Program class. This is azure function app, running on isolated worker model.
While the clientless pattern in static clients format works, the DI pattern doesnt.
FlurlHttp.Clients.WithDefaults(builder => builder
    .AddMiddleware(new MyDelegatingHandler()));

Above config works.
But this pattern below doesnt.
// DI pattern: 
services.AddSingleton<IFlurlClientCache>(sp => new FlurlClientCache()
    .WithDefaults(builder => builder
        .AddMiddleware(sp.GetService<IMyDelegatingHandler>())

I need the DI format, because my CustomDelegationHandler has other classes injected into it and it would have been easier if the DI version worked.
Since I dont have an interface, I used the below format. Wasnt sure about Interfaces for DelegatingHandlers.
Sample DelegationHandler being used:
public class MyDelegationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private static string CorrelationId => "correlation-id";

    private readonly ICorrelationIdQuery _correlationIdQuery;

    public MyDelegationHandler(ICorrelationIdQuery correlationIdQuery)
    {
        _correlationIdQuery = correlationIdQuery ;
    }

    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string correlationId = await _correlationIdQuery.Execute();

        if (!request.Headers.Contains(CorrelationId))
        {
            request.Headers.Add(CorrelationId, correlationId);
        }

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}

So my code becomes:
ServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
FlurlHttp.Clients.WithDefaults(builder => builder
        .AddMiddleware(() => new MyDelegationHandler(serviceProvider.GetService<ICorrelationIdQuery>())));

Above works, but not sure calling service provider like that is good idea in the Program class. This is the hostbuilder.ConfigureServices section and calling BuildServiceProvider in the middle is not good.
What can i be doing wrong in the below DI version of the code.
services.AddTransient<MyDelegationHandler>();
services.AddSingleton(sp => new FlurlClientCache()
    .WithDefaults(builder => builder
        .AddMiddleware(() => sp.GetService<MyDelegationHandler>())
    ));


I don't see the code where you registered your MyDelegationHandler in DI. Have you done that?

I am registering it. Corrected the example to reflect the same

I'd like to see an example of how you're actually using Flurl to make calls. In short, you can't really use the clientless pattern and DI together - they are opposing patterns.

List response = await $"https://localhost:7093/WeatherForecast"
.GetAsync()
.ReceiveJson<List>();
This is how i get it in the service. I see what you meant. This only works with the clientless pattern. With DI, i need to inject the IFlurlClientCache and get the client. But we dont use named clients. We have a large number of micro services and I was looking at a way to inject Correlation header into all calls made by the service to other services by a single configuration in the Program class.

Does that mean DI only works with named clients ? Like you need to have this on a minimum, right ?
private readonly IFlurlClient _flurlCli;
public LocalApiService(IFlurlClientCache clients)
{
_flurlCli = clients.GetOrAdd("LocalApiService");
_flurlCli.BaseUrl = "https://localhost:7093";
}

Yes. The name is nothing more than a cache key. The clientless pattern uses named clients too, but it picks a name for you by assuming you want to use the same client for all calls to the same host. Explicit usage means you're in control of the reuse strategy. If you don't like the idea of magic strings, using the base URL as the name is usually a fine choice.

As Todd Meiner explained in the comment, I was using opposing patterns.
DI config in the startup or Program class, but then the clientless pattern while making the Flurl http calls.
public class LocalApiService : ILocalApiService
{

    private readonly IFlurlClient _flurlCli;

    public LocalApiService(IFlurlClientCache clients)
    {
        _flurlCli = clients.GetOrAdd("LocalApiService");
        _flurlCli.BaseUrl = "https://localhost:7093";
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> GetStuffbyFlurl()
    {

        List<WeatherForecast> response = await _flurlCli.Request("WeatherForecast")
                                            .GetAsync()
                                            .ReceiveJson<List<WeatherForecast>>();

        //Do not use this clientless approach when you want DI to work
        //List<WeatherForecast> response = await $"https://localhost:7093/WeatherForecast"
        //            .GetAsync()
        //            .ReceiveJson<List<WeatherForecast>>();

        return response;
    }
}

A sample service which makes the flurl http call and works. Only thing is I would have to make it a named client, which means changing all the existing flurl classes in my usecase.
_flurlCli = clients.GetOrAdd("LocalApiService");

